# UnboundLocalError (Local variable referenced before assignment) Django

Tags: django-templates, django-views

For this feature, I am going to decrypt a string of morse code, back to a sentence.
But the error prompts out as saying **UnboundLocalError (local variable 'space' referenced before assignment)**

I researched online, people use *global* to solve the problem, but it doesn't work on me and I am only doing this locally, so I don't want it to affect my code later.

Here is my view:

```
def decipher(request):
    """The Decipher Page"""
    MORSE_CODE_DICT = {'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
                       'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
                       'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
                       'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
                       'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
                       'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
                       'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
                       'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
                       'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',

                       '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
                       '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
                       '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
                       '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
                       '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
                       '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-'}

    def decrypt(message):
        # extra space added at the end to access the
        # last morse code
        message += ' '
        decipherMsg = ''
        citext = ''
        for letter in message:
            # checks for space
            if letter != ' ':
                # counter to keep track of space
                space = 0
                # storing morse code of a single character
                citext += letter
                # in case of space
            else:
                # if i = 1 that indicates a new character
                space += 1
                # if i = 2 that indicates a new word
                if space == 2:
                    # adding space to separate words
                    decipherMsg += ' '
                else:
                    # accessing the keys using their values (reverse of encryption)
                    decipherMsg += list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.keys())[list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.values()).index(citext)]
                    citext = ''
        return decipherMsg

    val1 = request.GET.get('a1', '')
    res = decrypt(val1)

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/decipher.html', {'result': res})
```

My html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Decipher</h1>
    <form action="" method="get" >
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a1' ></textarea>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a2' > {{result}} </textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="cipher">Cipher</button>


        {% comment %}
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="a3" > {{result}} </textarea>
        {% endcomment %}
    </form>
{% endblock content  %}
```

Comment: Your `space` variable is not set outside the `for` loop, hence if it first takes the `else` it *uses* `space` before assigning it.

Comment: I tried initialise ```space = 0``` outside of for loop, too. But it gives me ***ValueError at /decipher/***, ***'' is not in list***

Comment: well that is a different error :)

Comment: can you share the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback:

File "Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

Comment: File "Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "Documents/morse_log/morse_logs/views.py" in decipher
  107.     res = decrypt(val1)

File "Documents/morse_log/morse_logs/views.py" in decrypt
  102.                     decipherMsg += list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.keys())[list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.values()).index(citext)]

Exception Type: ValueError at /decipher/
Exception Value: '' is not in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you *use* the `space` variable, before assigning it a value. This can happen if the first character of the message is for example a space.

Furthermore you better make a dictionary that maps in reverse, and perform a check that the `citext` contains at least one character:

```
MORSE_CODE_DICT_REV = {v: k for k, v in MORSE_CODE_DICT.items()}

def decrypt(message):
        # extra space added at the end to access the
        # last morse code
        message += ' '
        decipherMsg = ''
        citext = ''
        space = 0
        for letter in message:
            # checks for space
            if letter != ' ':
                # counter to keep track of space
                space = 0
                # storing morse code of a single character
                citext += letter
                # in case of space
            else:
                # if i = 1 that indicates a new character
                space += 1
                # if i = 2 that indicates a new word
                if space == 2:
                    # adding space to separate words
                    decipherMsg += ' '
                elif citext != '':
                    # accessing the keys using their values (reverse of encryption)
                    decipherMsg += MORSE_CODE_DICT_REV[citext]
                    citext = ''
        return decipherMsg
```